# Bjam: ignore specific library

Tags: c++, linker, bjam

Using Visual Studio, it is possible to 'Ignore Specific Library'
(Project Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Ignore
Specific Library).

We found this useful in a project. Now we want to build
that project using boost-build (bjam), but we need to reproduce that linker behaviour.

Is there any ignore library feature with bjam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set it at the command line

```
bjam linkflags=/NODEFAULTLIB:xxx
```

Or from within a jamfile

```
<linkflags>/NODEFAULTLIB:xxx
```

Or use Visual Studio's pragma comment feature in your code itself

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/NODEFAULTLIB:xxx")
```